# upgrading Docker EE for Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Docker EE installation followed here: https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/#install-docker-ee
for the script install. The uri seems to be broken. looking at download.docker.com it seems you dont have any of the new docker ee releases there (specifically 1809 that I’m looking to upgrade to) our network policies on our docker machines dont allow us to use PSGallery so I can’t follow the Install-Module approach…

Is there anything I can do to update to the latest docker ee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the direct download urls from [this json file](https://dockermsft.blob.core.windows.net/dockercontainer/DockerMsftIndex.json).

At the time of writing, the 1809 package zip is [here](https://dockermsft.blob.core.windows.net/dockercontainer/docker-18-09-0.zip) and seems to be the same version that the OneGet provider installs.

The link is actually included under section "Update Docker Engine - Enterprise" on the Docker docs page, but the offline installation should ideally include a method for discovering the url.

Comment: Thanks, I should have answered myself I found the json file a few days after posting!